# Can a chart-line show a legend like chart-radar (for instance)?

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart

I have the angularjs chartline:

```
  <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-series="series" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options" chart-legend="true">
    </canvas>
```

I want it to show legend (series) on the top of chart like how it works at chart-radar.
[image]

I have all settings for this, but it doesn't work properly:

```
   $scope.options = { legend: { display: true } };
```

[image]

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to add to the options namespace.
Like this:

```
  $scope.options = {

    legend: {display: true}

 };
```